# What is the proper way to upload a file to another application which providing service for document management?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now i am storing files in public folder.

After that i want to upload those file from public folder to another application which providing services for document management.

To upload document to another application. 
They provided link, username and password .

Like 
http://demo.testltd.com/V12345/search.aspx?username=test1&password=test2

How may i upload file from my public directory to the specific application ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Try [RestClient](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2008/3/9/rest_client/)

**EDIT**

I was sending data that I got from form

```
RestClient.post(server_path+"users",:user=>{ ... ,
                :avatar=>File.new("#{params[:avatar][:filename]}")}, 
                :multipart=>true)
```

Comment: i have tried RestClient but getting this error .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865313/file-upload-with-rest-client

Comment: Try to create new file inside your action with some simple filename and copy data into it from original file In the end of the action delete it